# Counting operation of i++

Tags: java, operation

Recently, I started to learn counting primitive operation and thus estimate the running time of a program. However, I found question in counting the operation of for loop.
Say,`for (int i=1; i<n; i++)`

Personally, I think `(i = 1)` for 1 time, `(i < n)` for n times, `i++` for `n-1` times and therefore `2n` times in total.
However, someone told me that `i++` for `n-1` times only counted how many times of the whole `i++` run. `i++` is equal to `i=i+1` and I should count it `2(n-1)` times.

Is it right to count `i++` twice? `++` represent a method or it's a operator?

Comment: Actually, the program, when compiled to the JVM language, does the work directly, not in two steps.  The Java Virtual Machine has an `iinc` statement (meaning increment integer in local variable). This gets done in a single operation. For example, ` iinc 0 1` means *increment local variable 0 by 1*.

Comment: @Eric Jablow I think your comment have solved my question. Thank you.

Comment: Similarly, x86 Assembly has the `inc` instruction, and languages that compile directly to assembler would use that.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
```

The *increment* block, which here is `i++`, is executed at the end of every iteration, so it's executed n-1 times. On the (n-1)th time, the *termination* condition is false and the loop terminates.

Comment: however, doesn't `i++` is doing `i=i+1`? if it executed n-1 times, shouldn't we time 2 to it?

Comment: @ting The whole purpose of `big O` is to abstract away each operation. `O(2n)` is on the same level as `O(n)`

Comment: `for all c != 0: x in O(cn) => x in O(n)`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I understand that constant and lower-order term wouldn't affect the growth rate. However, I still hope to know i++ is doing 1 operation or 2 operations. Thanks.

Comment: @Bohemian I am not sure if I understand you correctly. If `i=1` and we will use `n=1` then `i<n` will be false at start so incrementation of `i` will not happen because `for` code block will not be executed at all. If we would start from `i=0` then yes, we would execute `i++` `n` times.

Answer (score 1):

**1:**  Your loop is for n-1 times. This is because it will run for all the 'i' in:

> [ 1, n ) == [ 1, n-1 ]

**2:** ++ is an operator

Comment: It is not clear what your are trying to calculate with the math you do and "I should count it 2(n-1) times" is not clear either.. What you 'should count'?

Answer (score 0):

i++ is equals to i = i+1 so

1. calculating i+1
2. setting the result to i

2 steps in total, but 2 is just a constant so if you are using big O / Omega notation, it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the forloop in a different fashion:

`for(A,B,C)` can also be written as

```
A;
while(B){
...
C;
}
```

so A is a one-time initialisation, done before the loop runs

B is the condition, as long as the condition holds, the loop continues

C is done after every iteration, e.g incrementing a counter, i++

in your example, the loop will run n-1 times
i is initialized to 1
incremented after every loop
runs as long i

to the second part:
`++` is an operator, which is NOT equal to `i=i+1;`

`i` is incremented, but it returns the original `i`, not the incremented one

`++i` would be indeed equal to `i=i+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
```

In this block, i++ is called in every iteration and the check statement for this code block is `i<n` part.
So it is executed n times and for the nth time it does not pass the check statement and terminates

Answer (score 0):

`i++` is called unary operator in java. But you should count it twice. 
Because it 
- first makes and addition 
- then assignment.